# Action handler for Graphics 2d shapes?

Tags: java, user-interface

I need to draw shapes like arrow head lines connecting JButtons. But I also need them to be interactive. Is it possible to add action handlers for 2D shapes like lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add action handlers for 2D shapes like lines?

You can make your Shape a real component, then you can add your listeners directly to the component.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more information on this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If yours is a Swing GUI, then yes you can add this functionality to your GUI. Consider

- Create a MouseAdapter, a class that is both a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener (and can also listen to the wheel if desired).
- Add this to your drawing component via `addMouseListener(...)` and `addMouseMotionListener(...)`
- If you are using objects that eventually inherit from the Shape interface to do your drawing, then you can find out if mouse clicks are contained by the objects or not via the `contains(Point p)` method.